next/router useRouter not maintaining prevouse history
I am using useRouter of next/router to redirect between pages. When I click on the mobile browser's (like Chrome) back button, I'm not redirecting back to the previous page; instead, it redirects to the Chrome homepage or starting page from where I was initially.
next version 13.4.19
I am expecting if I click the back button of my mobile browser, I should be redirected to the previous page and not any other page.

Can you share your code, like how you are redirecting the user to a different page and all

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
router.push({
pathname: /page1/${slug}
});

Can you try to just do router.push(pathname)?

using this way also. but still getting same issue.
router.push(/therapist/${slug})

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

i think you use try router.back() it will help you to go back previous page

I am using chrome back button in ios and mobile back button in android. not doing back programmatically.
